# Can we ask staff for a new colour scheme?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-planned, design

In light of the new site-wide purple debacle - [Did the purple highlight just get worse?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394229/did-the-purple-highlight-just-get-worse) [& link to initial launch within] could we ask that our purple be swapped for something less… glaring?
The original design change was a bug, now fixed, but it really didn't improve things much.

Personally, I'd be happiest with a grey/black theme - keeping everything else as it is, just changing the areas currently purple - but see what Movies & Tv achieved, below.

[Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com), [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com) & [Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com) all look well on simple greyscale.
[Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com) manages an interesting combo of blue headline text, red voting arrows [matching their banner] and simple grey user cards - so it **can** be done in a more subtle way.

tbh, I don't mind the purple header text - you can barely tell it's purple. It's just the big, punchy highlights.

Examples

The bugged version
[image]

The fixed version
[image]

Fixed version with 'new contributor' highlight
[image]

Standard blue theme [as on most sites]
[image]

Better, less emphatic blue [SE Meta]
[image]

Plain grey, from Photography
[image]

IMO, the last two are best.

…and while we're asking, could we sort out the visited/not visited links in here. Purple to brown? Who thought that was a good idea?

> [image]

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and flagging this. Linking the [MSE request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394229/888623) here for visibility as well.

Comment: Thank you @SpencerG for the comment & status update. Most appreciated.